# Convert ppt ot pptx files to jpg

Tags: shell, scripting

I want to convert ppt or pptx to jpg files in server side. The user uploads ppt or pptx files and it is stored in the server as jpg files and displayed as pics discarding all animations. I have to use some shell scripting. Can this be done by shell scripting?

It is similar to what slideshare does it.
How does Slideshare do it?

Please suggest.

Comment: if you want to imitate slideshare why not use, [slideshare api](http://www.slideshare.net/developers?utm_source=MailingList&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=2010+-+A+Year+o)?

Comment: is there other alternative to do other than using the slideshare api? like pure shell script or something like that

Answer (score 2):

This website suggest using open office to convert the ppt to a pdf, and then convert this pdf to a thumbnail:

http://www.novell.com/communities/node/5744/c-linux-thumbnail-generation-pdfdocpptxlsimages

Comment: This link suggests that imagemagik or open office should be installed in the system but that would increase the overhead for the user. I want to have something which should convert the uploaded pptx or ppt to jpgs and store on the server side. Then it displays one slide at a time as a jpg.